# Switch for rock-paper-scissors

Tags: swift, switch-statement

I'm trying to make a simple rock-paper-scissors game. To do it I used a switch statement but for some reason it doesn't work properly.

This is the structure I thought of to make this little game:

There are three buttons for Rock,Scissors,Paper, and you have to choose one.
There is a Label that tells what the opponent (computer) chose, and I named it opponentLabel.
There is a Label that tells what the result is ("you won" for example) and I named it resultLabel

and it works like this (this just the way it's structured):

```
var a = Int()
if the player chooses Rock ---> a = 0
if the player chooses Paper ---> a = 1
if the player chooses Scissors ---> a = 2

For the opponent (computer, not a person) there is a randomNumber which
could be 0,1,2, and same here, if 0->opponent chose rock, if 
1->opponent chose paper, if 2-> opponent chose scissors
```

and then I wrote a switch statement that puts it all together.
The problem is that for some reason, when I run the app, if I choose rock everything works fine, but when I choose paper or scissors the results are wrong.

For example if I choose Paper (a = 1) and the opponent has paper (which means that the random number happened to be randomNumber = 1), the resultLabel is not "DRAW" as it would be supposed to be, but it is "You Lost": paper and scissors don't work !! What am I doing wrong? 
Here is the full code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet weak var opponentLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var resultLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var rockButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var paperButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var scissorsButton: UIButton!






override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    Hide()


}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



func Hide() {
    opponentLabel.hidden = true
    resultLabel.hidden = true
}

func unHide() {
    opponentLabel.hidden = false
    resultLabel.hidden = false
}


var a = Int()

var randomNumber = Int()

func randomChoice() {

    randomNumber = Int(arc4random() % 3)
    NSLog("randomNumber%ld", randomNumber)



}



func gameOn() {

    switch(randomNumber) { 

    case 0:
        opponentLabel.text = "The opponent chose : ROCK"
        if a == 0 {
            resultLabel.text = "DRAW"
        } else {
            if a == 1 {
                resultLabel.text = "YOU WON!"
            }
            if a == 2 {
                resultLabel.text = "YOU LOST!"
                }
        }
        unHide()
        break

    case 1:
        opponentLabel.text = "The opponent chose: PAPER"
        if a == 0 {
            resultLabel.text = "YOU LOST!"
        } else {
            if a == 1 {
                resultLabel.text = "DRAW"
            }
            if a == 2 {
                resultLabel.text = "YOU WON!"
            }
        }
        unHide()
        break

    case 2:
        opponentLabel.text = "The opponent chose: SCISSORS"
        if a == 0 {
            resultLabel.text = "YOU WON!"
        } else {
            if a == 1 {
                resultLabel.text = "YOU LOST!"
            }
            if a == 2 {
                resultLabel.text = "DRAW"
            }
        }
        unHide()
        break

    default:
        break


    }
}


@IBAction func rockButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    a == 0
    randomChoice()
    gameOn()

}


@IBAction func paperButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    a == 1
    randomChoice()
    gameOn()
}



@IBAction func scissorsButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    a == 2
    randomChoice()
    gameOn()

}



}
```

Comment: And you should avoid the break statement, except for the default case (because there isn't any action in it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your @IBAction functions, you are comparing 'a' with 0, 1 or 2 instead of giving 'a' that value.

Change your code so instead of a == 0, it's a = 0. Do this for the 3 @IBActions and try it again and it should work.

Comment: Thank you @AEkon !! It worked, and also.. I learned something new now!